# Передать значение в php

Tags: php

ребят подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть код

```
function test(form, page){
    var name_test = document.getElementById('name_test').value;
    var phone_test = document.getElementById('phone_test').value;
    var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
    var selectedCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.x:checked');
    var checkedValues = Array.from(selectedCheckBoxes).map(cb => cb.value);


 console.log(checkedValues);


    $.getJSON("/engine/ajax/php/test.php", {name_test:name_test, phone_test:phone_test, category:category, check:checkedValues},
    function(data){

        if(data.rez == 1)
        {...
```

Как правильно передать checkedValues в /test.php

в php использую

```
$checkted = htmlspecialchars($_GET['check']);
```

Спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: правольно передать функцию  checkedValues в пхп)

Comment: var name_test = document.getElementById('name_test').value;
    var phone_test = document.getElementById('phone_test').value;
    var category = document.getElementById('category').value; я передаю спокойно

Comment: Если у вас всё хорошо перёдаются, приведите пожалуйста что вам в PHP выдаст var_dump($_GET['check']);

Comment: ничего не выдает

Comment: var checkedValues = Array.from(selectedCheckBoxes).map(cb => cb.value);  После попробуйте добавить  checkedValues = JSON.stringify(checkedValues)

Comment: спасибо большое, я уже разобрался, сделал запись в input type hidden и с него взял val.